# Label keeps running off edge of ScrollView screen x axis Kivy

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I'm creating a chat screen, adding a `Label` to my `GridLayout` everytime the send button is pressed. However, my `Labels` run off the side of the screen when the text becomes too long, I would like them to wrap round and the text to go onto a new line but this isn't happening and I'm not sure why.

```
<ChatPage>:
    name: "chat_page"
    layout_content: layout_content

    NavigationLayout:
        id: nav_layout
        MDNavigationDrawer:
            NavigationDrawerIconButton:
                text: "Test"
                on_release: app.root.current = "login"

        FloatLayout:
            MDToolbar:
                pos_hint: {'top': 1}
                md_bg_color: 0.2, 0.6, 1, 1
                left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: root.ids.nav_layout.toggle_nav_drawer()]]

            ScrollView:
                size_hint: 0.95, 0.6
                pos_hint: {"x": 0.025, "top" : 0.8, "bottom" : 0.5}
                do_scroll_x: False
                GridLayout:
                    id: layout_content
                    cols: 2
                    size_hint_y: None
                    spacing: 10
                    height: self.minimum_height
                    canvas:
                        Color:
                            rgba: (1, 1, 1, 1)
                        Rectangle:
                            size: self.size
                            pos: self.pos

            BoxLayout:
                TextInput:
                    id: msg
                    hint_text: "Type your message here"
                    pos_hint: {"x": 0, "top": 0.15}
                    size_hint: 0.75, 0.15
                Button:
                    text: "Send"
                    background_normal: ""
                    background_color: 0, 0.6, 0, 1
                    pos_hint: {"x": 0.75, "top": 0.15}
                    size_hint: 0.25, 0.15
                    on_release: root.btn_press()

<SmoothLabel>:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: self.texture_size
    padding: 10, 10
    multiline: True
    background_color: 0,0,0,0
    background_normal: ""
    back_color: 1,0,1,1
    border_radius: [6]
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.2,0.6,1,1 #This changes the label colour
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            radius: self.border_radius
```

py file

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty, NumericProperty, ListProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager
import mysql.connector
from kivymd.uix.picker import MDDatePicker
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView

Window.clearcolor = (1,1,1,1)


class SmoothLabel(Label):
    pass


class ChatPage(Screen):
    layout_content = ObjectProperty(None)
    def btn_press(self):
        if self.ids.msg.text:
            lab1 = Label()
            self.layout_content.add_widget(SmoothLabel(text=self.ids.msg.text))
            self.layout_content.add_widget(lab1)
            self.ids.msg.text = ""
        else:
            pass


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class MyApp(App):
    theme_cls = ThemeManager()

    def build(self):
        kv = Builder.load_file("kivy.kv")
        sm = WindowManager()

        screens = [ChatPage(name="chat_page")]
        for screen in screens:
            sm.add_widget(screen)

        sm.current = "chat_page"
        return sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `btn_press` method, change:

```
self.layout_content.add_widget(SmoothLabel(text=self.ids.msg.text))
```

to:

```
self.layout_content.add_widget(SmoothLabel(text=self.ids.msg.text, text_size=(self.layout_content.width, None)))
```

Adding the `text_size` allows the `Label` to wrap at the specified width.

Comment: Thanks for this, however it creates a ```Label``` that is the entire width of the screen regardless of how much text is in the ```Label```. How do I adjust it so that it the label only gets wider with the amount of text that it contains.

Answer (score 0):

I should insist that you submit your new question as a separate post. But here is another answer that handles both your questions:

Using the concept of the `text_size` along with calculating the `SmoothLabel` size with `kivy.core.text.Label`, a size adjusted `SmoothLabel` can be created.

Adding a static method to `SmoothLabel`:

```
class SmoothLabel(Label):
    @staticmethod
    def create_sized_label(**kwargs):
        max_width = kwargs.pop('max_width', 0)
        if max_width <= 0:
            # just create a SmoothLabel without a text_size
            return SmoothLabel(**kwargs)

        # calculate what the SmoothLabel size will be
        core_label = CoreLabel(padding=[10,10], **kwargs)  # use same padding as SmoothLabel
        core_label.refresh()

        if core_label.width > max_width:
            # width is too big, use text_size to force wrapping
            return SmoothLabel(text_size=(max_width,None), **kwargs)
        else:
            # width is OK, no need for text_size
            return SmoothLabel(**kwargs)
```

Then use that method in the `ChatPage`:

```
class ChatPage(Screen):
    layout_content = ObjectProperty(None)
    def btn_press(self):
        if self.ids.msg.text:
            lab1 = Label()

            # calculate max allowable width in the GridLayout
            max_width = self.layout_content.width - self.layout_content.spacing[0] - self.layout_content.padding[0] - self.layout_content.padding[2]

            # specify font and font_size (so that the CoreLabel uses the same)
            self.layout_content.add_widget(SmoothLabel.create_sized_label(text=self.ids.msg.text, max_width=max_width, font_name='Roboto', font_size=15))

            self.layout_content.add_widget(lab1)
            self.ids.msg.text = ""
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: Thanks, this hasn't worked unfortunately, long text is still causing the ```Label``` to run off the edge of the screen. Shall I ask this as a separate question?

Comment: Did you include `from kivy.core.text import Label as CoreLabel` in your py file?

Comment: I didn't at first but after getting the error saying CoreLabel wasn't recognised I assumed I needed to import it with ```Label```. After doing this it ran without any errors but just didn't stop the ```Label``` and text running off the screen

Comment: Make sure you import it exactly as mentioned in my comment above.

Comment: Ah apologies, didn't import it correctly first time. It works most of the time but having tried ~10 labels of varying size not all of them are wrapping correctly. Have you experienced this when trying multiple labels of all different sizes?

Comment: Yes, upon closer examination I see better accuracy needed. I have modified my answer to account for spacing and padding in both the `GridLayout` and the `SmoothLabel`. I also added `font_name` and `font_size` to insure both the `SmoothLabel` and `CoreLabel` use the same. I think it works better now.