# Adding labels to IM/Chat screen kivy

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to make a screen in my kivy app where two users can chat with each other but I'm having trouble with how to display the chat messages on the screen.

Example of roughly what I'm aiming for: (scroll ~60% down the page to see it)
https://medium.com/flutter-community/building-a-chat-app-with-flutter-and-firebase-from-scratch-9eaa7f41782e

I've used this answer to add labels to the left hand side of the screen (messages sent by the user):
[Label keeps running off edge of ScrollView screen x axis Kivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59696424/label-keeps-running-off-edge-of-scrollview-screen-x-axis-kivy)

But I'm now trying to work out how I add labels to the right hand side of the screen (messages received by the user). I assume I need a `GridLayout` with two columns and I need to add a white label first and then add the message label afterwards, then it should appear on the right. I'm having problems with getting the label to appear as far right as it can on the screen.

I'm also having trouble with the labels resizing depending on the amount of text in each label, I think I might need to add each row in as a new `GridLayout`

Surely something like this has been done with kivy already and there's a guide to follow but I've searched around and all I can find is old-school UI chat screen designs.

py file

```
import kivy
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty, NumericProperty, ListProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.text import Label as CoreLabel
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFillRoundFlatButton, MDRoundFlatIconButton, MDRaisedButton, MDTextButton, MDIconButton
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.size = (481, 600)
Window.clearcolor = (1,1,1,1)

class Chat(Screen):
    chat_layout = ObjectProperty(None)
    def send_message(self):
        if self.ids.message.text:
            lab1 = Label()

            # calculate max allowable width in the GridLayout
            max_width = self.chat_layout.width - self.chat_layout.spacing[0] - self.chat_layout.padding[0] - \
                        self.chat_layout.padding[2]

            # specify font and font_size (so that the CoreLabel uses the same)
            self.chat_layout.add_widget(
                SmoothLabel.create_sized_label(text=self.ids.message.text, max_width=max_width, font_name='Roboto',
                                               font_size=15))

            self.chat_layout.add_widget(lab1)
            self.ids.message.text = ""
        else:
            pass

    def recv_message(self):
        if self.ids.message.text:
            # calculate max allowable width in the GridLayout
            max_width = self.chat_layout.width - self.chat_layout.spacing[0] - self.chat_layout.padding[0] - \
                        self.chat_layout.padding[2]

            # specify font and font_size (so that the CoreLabel uses the same)
            chat_label = SmoothLabel.create_sized_label(text=self.ids.message.text, max_width=max_width, font_name='Roboto',
                                               font_size=15)
            lab1 = Label(width=max_width)
            self.chat_layout.add_widget(lab1)
            self.chat_layout.add_widget(chat_label)
            self.ids.message.text = ""
        else:
            pass

class SmoothLabel(Label):
    @staticmethod
    def create_sized_label(**kwargs):
        max_width = kwargs.pop('max_width', 0)
        if max_width <= 0:
            # just create a SmoothLabel without a text_size
            return SmoothLabel(**kwargs)

        # calculate what the SmoothLabel size will be
        core_label = CoreLabel(padding=[10,10], **kwargs)  # use same padding as SmoothLabel
        core_label.refresh()

        if core_label.width > max_width:
            # width is too big, use text_size to force wrapping
            return SmoothLabel(text_size=(max_width,None), **kwargs)
        else:
            # width is OK, no need for text_size
            return SmoothLabel(**kwargs)

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        kv = Builder.load_file("kivy.kv")
        self.sm = WindowManager()

        screens = [Chat(name="chat")]
        for screen in screens:
            self.sm.add_widget(screen)

        self.sm.current = "chat"
        return self.sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

kv file

```
<Chat>:
    name: "chat"
    chat_layout: chat_layout

    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            id: chat_layout
            padding: 15

        GridLayout:
            cols: 3
            MDRaisedButton:
                on_release: root.send_message()
                text: "send message"
            TextInput:
                id: message
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 150,50
                hint_text:
                    "Send message"
            MDRaisedButton:
                on_release: root.recv_message()
                text: "receive message"

<SmoothLabel>:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: self.texture_size
    padding: 10, 10
    multiline: True
    background_color: 0,0,0,0
    background_normal: ""
    back_color: 1,0,1,1
    border_radius: [6]
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.2,0.6,1,1 #This changes the label colour
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            radius: self.border_radius
```

Comment: I've tried printing various width properties of ```chat_label``` (```size```,```size_hint_x```,```width```,```texture_size```) but they all return ```None```. I was thinking if I can get the width of the ```chat_label``` then I can add a blank label beforehand, which is max_width minus the width of the ```chat_label```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do what you want by using a `BoxLayout` instead of a `GridLayout`, and using `pos_hint` to position the chat labels on the left or right:

```
import kivy
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty, NumericProperty, ListProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.text import Label as CoreLabel
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFillRoundFlatButton, MDRoundFlatIconButton, MDRaisedButton, MDTextButton, MDIconButton
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.size = (481, 600)
Window.clearcolor = (1,1,1,1)

class Chat(Screen):
    chat_layout = ObjectProperty(None)
    def send_message(self):
        if self.ids.message.text:
            # calculate max allowable width in the BoxLayout
            max_width = (self.chat_layout.width - self.chat_layout.spacing - self.chat_layout.padding[0] - \
                        self.chat_layout.padding[2]) * 0.75

            # specify font and font_size (so that the CoreLabel uses the same)
            self.chat_layout.add_widget(
                SmoothLabel.create_sized_label(text=self.ids.message.text, max_width=max_width, font_name='Roboto',
                                               font_size=15, pos_hint={'x':0}))
            self.ids.message.text = ""
            self.ids.scroll.scroll_y = 0  # make sure last message is visible
        else:
            pass

    def recv_message(self):
        if self.ids.message.text:
            # calculate max allowable width in the BoxLayout
            max_width = (self.chat_layout.width - self.chat_layout.spacing - self.chat_layout.padding[0] - \
                        self.chat_layout.padding[2]) * 0.75

            # specify font and font_size (so that the CoreLabel uses the same)
            self.chat_layout.add_widget(
                SmoothLabel.create_sized_label(text=self.ids.message.text, max_width=max_width, font_name='Roboto',
                                               font_size=15, pos_hint={'right':1}))
            self.ids.message.text = ""
            self.ids.scroll.scroll_y = 0  # make sure last message is visible
        else:
            pass

class SmoothLabel(Label):
    @staticmethod
    def create_sized_label(**kwargs):
        max_width = kwargs.pop('max_width', 0)
        if max_width <= 0:
            # just create a SmoothLabel without a text_size
            return SmoothLabel(**kwargs)

        # calculate what the SmoothLabel size will be
        core_label = CoreLabel(padding=[10,10], **kwargs)  # use same padding as SmoothLabel
        core_label.refresh()

        if core_label.width > max_width:
            # width is too big, use text_size to force wrapping
            return SmoothLabel(text_size=(max_width,None), **kwargs)
        else:
            # width is OK, no need for text_size
            return SmoothLabel(**kwargs)


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

kv_str = '''
<Chat>:
    name: "chat"
    chat_layout: chat_layout

    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        ScrollView:
            id: scroll
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                id: chat_layout
                padding: 15
                spacing: 15
                size_hint: 1, None
                height: self.minimum_height

        GridLayout:
            cols: 3
            MDRaisedButton:
                on_release: root.send_message()
                text: "send message"
            TextInput:
                id: message
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 150,50
                hint_text:
                    "Send message"
            MDRaisedButton:
                on_release: root.recv_message()
                text: "receive message"

<SmoothLabel>:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: self.texture_size
    padding: 10, 10
    multiline: True
    background_color: 0,0,0,0
    background_normal: ""
    back_color: 1,0,1,1
    border_radius: [6]
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.2,0.6,1,1 #This changes the label colour
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            radius: self.border_radius
'''

class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        # kv = Builder.load_file("kivy.kv")
        Builder.load_string(kv_str)
        self.sm = WindowManager()

        screens = [Chat(name="chat")]
        for screen in screens:
            self.sm.add_widget(screen)

        self.sm.current = "chat"
        return self.sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

I added `spacing` to the `BoxLayout` and eliminated the empty `Labels` that are no longer needed.

I used `Builder.load_string()` instead of `load_file()` just for my own convenience.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise you could position ```BoxLayout``` widgets, that makes it a lot simpler. The only thing is the ```chat_label``` width is always set to the ```max_width``` with this expression ```text_size=(max_width, None)```, I'd like to make it take into account how much text is in the label, so it maybe be narrower if there's not much text in it. I assume I need to do something like ```text_size=(chat_label.width, None), max_width=max_width``` but I know ```chat_label.width``` is not how I refer to the width of it. How would I do this?

Comment: Oops, sorry, I misinterpreted your question and thought you wanted the width of `chat_label` to always be the same. You can restore your `create_sized_label()` method and use that approach to calculate the width of `chat_label`.

Comment: I have tried adding back ```create_sized_label()``` such as ```chat_label = SmoothLabel.create_sized_label(text=self.ids.message.text, text_size=(max_width, None), font_name='Roboto', 
                                               font_size=15, pos_hint={'right':1})``` but it hasn't changed anything, I've probably implemented it wrong - I don't fully understand how the ```create_sized_label``` adjusts the size.

Comment: I have updated my answer so that it uses `create_sized_label()` again.

Comment: Thanks, not sure what changed but it works perfectly now

Comment: I'm trying to make the chat page a scrollable, which isn't an issue with ```GridLayouts``` but it seems to be quite tricky when using a ```BoxLayout```. I didn't think it was relevant to this question so I didn't include it but now we've added the ```BoxLayout``` I'm unsure how to alter it to get it to scroll.                    ```GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            id: chat_layout
            padding: 15
            spacing: 15``` How would I change this to add a scrollview in? Should I create this a seperate SO question?

Comment: Normally. I would say that this should be a separate question, but it's a quick, easy fix. I have updated my answer to incorporate a `ScrollView` to contain the `BoxLayout`. The key is the use of `height: self.minimum_height` for the `BoxLayout`.

Comment: Thanks, that was easier than I thought